# take today's values between given hours in defined date-time format

Tags: mysql, datetime, between

I have to make a **SELECT** from a table where the field with the time is in format: **y-m-d h-m-s** but I have to output the values that are entered for the current day between 00:00:01 and 23:59:59. My query looks like that:

```
SELECT user, insert_time FROM t_users
WHERE insert_time BETWEEN '2014-06-30 00-00-01' AND '2014-06-30 23-59-59'
```

The problem is that I don't have to hardcode the date... only the hours interval. And to make it better to understand the current problem I will make a wrong input what is needed to be done: `'TODAY 00-00-01' AND 'TODAY 23-59-59'` which of course don't work but if there is a way to make a query that will output the today's added values, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of calculation with PHP:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/

or MysQL solution:

http://blog.ubiq.co/difference-between-two-dates/

Also for today entries I think you can use:

```
SELECTid FROM my_table 
WHERE
timestamp < date_format(date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), interval 1 day),'%Y%m%d000000')
AND
timestamp >= date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y%m%d000000')
```